# Are there other places with gardens like those at Versailles?

Tags: europe, parks-and-gardens, versailles

The [Gardens of Versailles](http://en.chateauversailles.fr/gardens-and-park-of-the-chateau-) are world famous, and [apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gardens_of_Versailles) receive over 6 million visitors a year. They're stunning gardens to visit, but I can't help but think that some other European courts might have decided to build their own similar.

Are there any other similar parks elsewhere in Europe that can be visited? Ideally ones still in / restored to the Versailles style?

Comment: I think this is a great example of a question that has more than one "right answer" but is still a very good and suitable question for our site.

Answer (score 17):

On the Italian side there is:

[Reggia di Caserta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palace_of_Caserta) 
[image: Reggia di Caserta]

[Villa Boboli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boboli_Gardens)
[image: Giardini di villa Boboli]

[Villa Lante](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villa_Lante)
[image: Villa Lante]

[Giardino Giusti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palazzo_Giusti)
[image: Giardino Giusti]

[Isola Bella](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isola_Bella_%28Lago_Maggiore%29)
[image: Isola Bella]

[Villa d'Este](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Villa_d%27Este)

[image: Villa d'Este]

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is! 750km North-East of Paris is the delightful city of Hanover (Hannover), which has the Great Gardens at [Herrenhausen Gardens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herrenhausen_Gardens) (Großen Garten of Herrenhäuser Gärten)

This was largely laid out in the late 17th century, and one of the leading gardeners from Versailles was commissioned to help lay it out, so the styles of the two are very similar!

It's a bit easier to get to than Versailles is from Paris - it's about 10 minutes on the tram from the city centre, or you can walk down the tree lined avenue from the city centre through Georgengarten (park).

Sadly I didn't have a good camera with me, but here's [a cc photo from dierkschaefer from Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dierkschaefer/3700867022/) that shows what it's like:
[image: dierkschaefer from Flickr]

And another, this one from [grebein](http://www.flickr.com/photos/grebein/5794982118/) which shows more of the fountains in full display:
[image: cc photo from grebein from Flickr]

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herrenhausen_Gardens) also has an aerial shot, which gives more of an idea of the scope + layout

Answer (score 10):

Vienna and its surrounding has several gardens:

- Volksgarten Wien:
  [image]
- Palace Schönbrunn
  [image]
- Augarten Wien
  [image]

Answer (score 8):

There are quite a few in the UK as well, with [Blenheim Palace](http://www.blenheimpalace.com/) being probably the most famous (but by any chance not the only one). The gardens look like this:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure Blenheim is quite in the same league, but it does have the definite advantage that I can cycle there in well under an hour from home :)

Comment: Blenheim is not on the same scale as Versailles, but plus points for convenience.

Answer (score 8):

Peterhof just outside St-Petersburg is really amazing.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I can add 2 more beautiful gardens in Germany:

- [Sanssouci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanssouci) near Berlin
  [image: Sanssouci]
- [Schwetzingen Schlossgarten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwetzingen_Castle) near Heidelberg
  [image: Schwetzingen]

Answer (score 7):

Although the style is a bit different than the gardens in Versailles, the [Hellbrunn Palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellbrunn_Palace) (Schloss Hellbrunn) outside Salzburg makes for an impressive visit nevertheless.

[Aerial shot](http://www.itourmap.com/attraction.php?city=Salzburg&id=Schloss_Hellbrunn)
[image: schloss hellbrun 1]

[Part of the fountain](http://www.kitzbuehel-alpen.com/nl/meer-mogelijkheden-voor-uitsta.html)
[image: schloss hellbrun 2]

The gardens and fountains make for a pleasant visit, but the real joy is that the grounds were rigged to play practical jokes on visitors by the archbishop who commissioned the palace's construction, so the stone seats throughout the garden contain fountains that spray visitors (they still operate) and water-operated musical theatre is designed to soak the audience.

In short, the grounds are beautiful, and it makes for a good history lesson when you learn what the slightly immature prince-archbishop of Salzburg did in his free time.

Answer (score 5):

In Portugal, just outside of Lisbon, there is the [Queluz National Palace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queluz_National_Palace) which is famous for its gardens and is often referred to as the Portuguese Versailles.

[image: gardnes]

Answer (score 3):

I've long thought of the [Tivoli Gardens of Copenhagen, Denmark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tivoli_Gardens)  as being somewhat similar to Versailles.

It has the "fountains and flowers" generally associated with Versailles. But Tivoli was created as an amusement park with the intent of having the OPPOSITE effect of Versailles. That is, King Christian VIII created it for the "people" to defuse the possibility of revolution, while Louis XIV created Versailles for himself and other "royals" and aristocrats, thereby increasing the probability of the French Revolution.

Answer (score 3):

You can see a list of French formal garden (*jardins à la francaise*) at the end of the [wikipedia article on the topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_formal_garden).

Answer (score 2):

and don't forget [Paleis het Loo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paleis_het_Loo) in Apeldoorn, the Netherlands (wiki page includes a link to a list of baroque style homes and palaces) for further inspiration)
While a lot smaller, they're rather charming. An active residence, only part of the palace and its gardens is open to the public.